# ASP.NET Forms authentication behind a reverse proxy with different path

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, reverse-proxy

I have an ASP.NET web application with forms authentication. It resides at `https://internal-IP/AppName/`. The forms authentication is configured thus:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/Home/News/" protection="All" timeout="120" name=".BLAH" requireSSL="true" slidingExpiration="true" cookieless="UseCookies" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
```

It works fine.

But then, we have an Apache reverse proxy that lets external users access vis `https://proxy-url/ProjectName/AppName/`. As you can see, there is one more folder level in the path than the original app has.

Consequently, `~/Login.aspx` redirects to `https://proxy-url/AppName/Login.aspx` instead of `https://proxy-url/ProjectName/AppName/Login.aspx`.

Is there a work-around for this? For example, define some static base path for the value of `~`?

Thank you for any help.

Chris.

Comment: How did you solve this? I have a similar issue

Comment: We didn't. We worked around it by creating virtual directories on the web server to reflect the path imposed by the proxy.